# LINQ WITH VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql

Is the VS 2008 professeional Edition fully  support with linq to sql

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is available. But not the current best practice by Microsoft. It became available with .NET 3.5.

Comment: References, please. EF 4.0 was released in VS2010, not 2008.

Comment: @Robert http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx, seems like .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Yep, seen that already.  Also saw the mountain of FUD that was spread because of it.

Comment: @Robert: from your link: *We said we would improve the core of it and add customer requests where it makes sense but that Entity Framework would be the primary focus*